# playing second Sound

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

am trying to do a simple AVAudioPlayer based application to play 2 different music upon button pressed, there is 2 views, the first is the home view contains 2 buttons,each button set a song which is named as integer(1.mp3, 2.mp3.....etc)and here'e the code

```
#import "podHome.h"
#import "podMusic.h"
#import "ArabAppDelegate.h"


@implementation podHome

@synthesize song1;
@synthesize tabi;   
int CurrentPlay;
NSString *Currenttxt;


-(IBAction)uae{
    CurrentPlay=1;
    Currenttxt=@"uae";
    podMusic *newContro=[[podMusic alloc] init];
    [newContro setCurrentPlay1:CurrentPlay setCurrentText:Currenttxt];

    ArabAppDelegate *theDelegate = (ArabAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    tabi = theDelegate.tabcontrolPod;
    tabi.selectedIndex = 1;
    [newContro release];
}

-(IBAction)libya{
    CurrentPlay=2;
    Currenttxt=@"uae";
    podMusic *newContro=[[podMusic alloc] init];
    [newContro setCurrentPlay1:CurrentPlay setCurrentText:Currenttxt];

    ArabAppDelegate *theDelegate = (ArabAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    tabi = theDelegate.tabcontrolPod;
    tabi.selectedIndex = 1;
    [newContro release];
}
```

these tow (IBActions) are linked to the two buttons when pressing on one of them it will change to the other view and start playing the song

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    if((played == 1)&&(isBacked==FALSE)){

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:texting 
                                                         ofType:@"txt"];

    NSString *filenameString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
    CurrentTex.text = filenameString;
    AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
        AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
        AudioSessionSetActive(YES);  

        playBtnBG = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"play-pod.png"] retain];
        pauseBtnBG = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause-pod.png"] retain];
        [playButton setBackgroundImage:pauseBtnBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self registerForBackgroundNotifications];

        updateTimer = nil;

        duration.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        currentTime.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        progressBar.minimumValue = 0.0; 
        NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",CurrentPlay] ofType:@"mp3"];
        self.player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        [player stop];
        //self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];    
        if (self.player)
        {
            [self updateViewForPlayerInfo:player];
            [self updateViewForPlayerState:player];
            player.numberOfLoops = 0;
            player.delegate = self;
        }
        [self startPlaybackForPlayer:player];
        fileName.text= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", songName];
      // [fileURL release];
//        CurrentPlay = 0;
               isBacked = TRUE;
    }

        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)setCurrentPlay1:(int)varP setCurrentText:(NSString *)varT{

    CurrentPlay = varP;
    texting = varT;
    played = 1;
    isBacked = FALSE;
}
```

but the problem is that when the song is playing and am back to home view and pressing on the other song's button, it starts to play with the first one at the same time, i think the first should stop to begin the other, what should i release to do that???

Comment: Interesting function names there.... :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have two instances of the AVAudioPlayer, and when you set them both to play, they both do!

One solution would be to tell other players to stop when you activate a new one, but that will quickly become troublesome as the number of players increases.

Instead you;'d be better of just setting up one player, and change it's song in accordance to what button was pressed. That way, there is no chance that two music tracks will play at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In your first button action write like this.

```
if(player2.isPlaying)
{
[player2 stop];
}
```

in the same way do the same thing in second button action like this.

```
if(player1.isPlaying)
{
[player1 stop];
}
```